# How Ganeti deals with Fencing

Tags: high-availability, ganeti, fencing

I found out that proxmox doc says a lot abou [Fencing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fencing_%28computing%29). I haven't found anything about it in Ganeti doc. Also I screeched Ganeti Google Group Archive and I found similar question but answer was that Split Brain is not a problem in Ganeti and questioner should read archive.

So I wonder if Ganeti solved in some creative way or just ignored the problem?
I'm especially interested in setups with only two nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I founded answer for my question - Ganeti has only manual failover. Fencing is only needed in case of automatic failover to prevent concurrent access to the same resource (since in case of split nodes with quorum can't be sure if other nodes are dead ore there is only communication problem - [STONITH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STONITH)), but in case on manual failover you relay on admins's judgement.

Answer (score 3):

Maciek, you're correct, Ganeti only provides manual failover. With the `oob` framework we have the basic capability to do STONITH (via integration with a site-local framework; see internal documentation at [docs.ganeti.org](http://docs.ganeti.org/ganeti/master/html/design-oob.html)), but we have not yet extended this to automatic failover.

Comment: So does it still needs manual intervention?

Comment: @chandank - yes; in the 2.7 version (soon in beta) we have some experimental linux-ha ocf scripts, and we have an auto-repair tool in development, but things are not yet working "out-of-the-box".

Comment: That sounds cool, I will give a try once 2.7 is out.